# How does Django Rest Framework permission_classes work?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't understand why the permission_classes attribute of a GenericView is a list. Say why is it

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

and not

```
permission_class = IsAdminUser
```

? Also can I put 2 or more elements in the list, if so how do I interpret this?

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated]
```

Is the snippet above the same as

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser & IsAuthenticated]
```

?
Also how should I interpret bitwise OR on the permissions?

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser | IsAuthenticated]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why this is list like `permission_classes = [A, B]`

Let assume the you want to check multiple condition like the authenticated user must be an admin and the HTTP request will come from 172.123.12.12/32.

That time you can use `IsAdminUser` and `IsWhiteListedIP` as `permission_classes = [IsAdminUser , IsWhiteListedIP]`.

If you avoid list then both `WhileListedIP` and `IsAdminUser` logic is needed to implement in single class. That will compromise reuse of class. Hence, each class (`WhileListedIP` and `IsAdminUser` ) only focus on specific task; you can use those separate in views and viewset independently.

When you provide a list in `permission_classes`, all have to pass without any exception. So, yes, those are acting as `&` condition.

Answer (score -1):

From DRF permission [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)

> Provided they inherit from
>   `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission`, permissions can be
>   composed using standard Python bitwise operators.
>
> For example, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly could be written:
>
> ```
> class ExampleView(APIView):
>     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly]
>
>     def get(self, request, format=None):
>         content = {
>             'status': 'request was permitted'
>         }
>         return Response(content)
> ```

Default list behavior is same as & (AND)